# SSIS - Extra Derived Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

How to convert this below SQL code in SSIS package , Since i am trying to use this same SQL code in Extra Derived Column , but here i am getting error.

SQL Code:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE ([MeasureName]),PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE ([MeasureName])),50))

Please suggest me

Error Msg:

------------------------------

Error at  DRIVE [Extra Derived Columns [1567]]: Parsing the expression "REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE ([MeasureName]),PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE ([MeasureName])),50))" failed. The single quotation mark at line number "1", character number "52", was not expected.

Error at  DRIVE [Extra Derived Columns [1567]]: Cannot parse the expression "REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE ([MeasureName]),PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE ([MeasureName])),50))". The expression was not valid, or there is an out-of-memory error.

Error at  DRIVE [Extra Derived Columns [1567]]: The expression "REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE ([MeasureName]),PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE ([MeasureName])),50))" on "output column "Derived Column 1" (2025)" is not valid.

Error at  DRIVE [Extra Derived Columns [1567]]: Failed to set property "Expression" on "output column "Derived Column 1" (2025)".

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can read?  `The single quotation mark at line number "1"` change single qoutation mark to double quatation mark `'% %'` -> `"% %"`

Comment: Hi Justin , Sorry no luck , i tried to change single qout to double

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in SSIS there is no `PATINDEX` in SSIS you need to use [FINDSTRING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx)`:

```
FINDSTRING(character_expression, searchstring, occurrence)
```

Returns the location of the specified occurrence of a string within a character expression

This don't throw error, but probably is not what you want, because I don't know what you try to achieve with your string:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Company]),FINDSTRING("% %",REVERSE([Company]),1),50))
```